# TextField blur not working in Nativescript vue

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, nativescript

I have a TextField component with `keyboardType="phone"`, but there's an issue using phone type, because user won't be able to close that numpad, so i've tried to use built-in events:

```
<Textfield
  hint="Some hint text"
  keyboardType="phone"
  @blur="dismissKeyboard"
/>
```

Here's the method:

```
methods: {
  dismissKeyboard() {
    alert('Keyboard dismissed')
  }
}
```

But it never fired, when i press on text input, type a phone number, then click on other elements, blur event is not fired.

Comment: I am suspecting that the blur event will only fire if focus is gained only by a another textfield. Tapping in the void or a button won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

`blur` is an event, you must use it like this (add a `@`):

```
<Textfield
  hint="Some hint text"
  keyboardType="phone"
  @blur="dismissKeyboard"
/>
```

Comment: Well, i've tried with `@blur` before, it didn't work. What else could be causing this issue?